# Локализованные ресурсы(масивы) и их использывание

Tags: java, android, xml, android-sdk

Как правильно реализовать роботу локализованных ресурсов?
Делаю так: создаю новый файл ресурсов `strings` через ПКМ-New-Valuse и там задаю странну, ну и язык. Получаю уже два файла(правда флаг не тот, но не важно, надеюсь на функционал не влияет).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеются такие массивы:

```
<string-array name="food">

    <item>Тефтели</item>
    <item>Яблоко</item>
    <item>Пельмени</item>
    <item>Ананас</item>
    <item>Капуста</item>
    <item>Кабачок</item>
    <item>Опельсин</item>
    <item>Лемон</item>
    <item>Желе</item>
    <item>Мед</item>
    <item>Сосиска</item>
    <item>Пицца</item>
    <item>Лук</item>
    <item>Лемонад</item>
    <item>Чай</item>

</string-array>

<string-array name="food">

    <item>Noisettes</item>
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Pelmeni</item>
    <item>Pineaple</item>
    <item>Cabbage</item>
    <item>Squash</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
    <item>Lemon</item>
    <item>Jelly</item>
    <item>Honney</item>
    <item>Sausage</item>
    <item>Pizza</item>
    <item>Onion</item>
    <item>Lemonade</item>
    <item>Tea</item>

</string-array>
```

Делаю так:

```
String[] food = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food);
```

И вот вопрос, правильно ли я это делаю? А то проверить не получается.

Comment: Не знаю, правильно ли, но почему нельзя проверить? Поменяйте язык в эмуляторе (или на девайсе) и посмотрите, что получилось.

Comment: Всё правильно. Только "Лимонад" и "Апельсин".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы все делаете правильно. Стоит заметить, что в *Android Studio* есть встроенный редактор локализации - [*Translation Editor*](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/translations-editor.html), который сильно облегчает работу, как по созданию новой локализации, так и редактированию существующей.
Инструмент сам создаст необходимые папки и файлы, вам требуется только выбрать язык и, собственно, заполнить сам перевод в таблице строковых ресурсов.

Иконка редактора - синий глобус, попасть туда можно из визуального редактора разметки, открыв любой Layout или нажав на кнопку-ссылку *Open Editor*, открыв любой файл строковых ресурсов, так же можно кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши на любом файле строковых ресурсов и выбрать *Open Translations Editor*